# What is an alternative to Regression Discontinuity if the forcing variable is dichotomous?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, regression-discontinuity

We conducted a pilot study where we used a validated scoring instrument to test for self-reported depression. The instrument does not have a quantitative cut-off, though- it's more to the effect of "if ptnt answers yes to any 3 questions, then they meet the criteria for depression." Patients who met the criteria (eg were positive on the screening tool) underwent the intervention, while those who did not screen + did not undergo the intervention. Data was gathered on both groups at follow up. In order to use a regression discontinuity design, the forcing variable has to be continuous. Does anybody know of any alternative methods of analysis that are similar to the Sharp RD design, but have a dichotomous forcing variable?

Comment: It seem like you could just use differences in differences for this.